# How to update elements on existing array C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, exception

I have a problem on my music player C# application, If I add new files using open file dialogue. The array is not adding the new files. Then it will show the **Selected Index Array Index out of bound** exception error on `player.URL = path[track_list.SelectedIndex];` on the following line. So how to handle this exception ? How to update the new elements on the array ?

```
string[] files, path;

        private void Track_list_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        
            player.URL = path[track_list.SelectedIndex];
    }

 private void Btn_import_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        //ofd is the instance of open file dialogue
            ofd.Multiselect = true;
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                //add the file name into two arrays
                files = ofd.SafeFileNames;
                path = ofd.FileNames;

                for (int i=0; i<files.Length; i++)
                {
                //add songs into the items box
                    track_list.Items.Add(files[i]); 
                }
                
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you ever instantiate the array and assign it a size?

Comment: Please debug your code and [edit] question with at least following: value of `track_list.SelectedIndex` when it fails, content of `path` when it fails, content of `path` after `Btn_import_Click_1` as well as in which order Btn_import_Click_1 and Track_list_SelectedIndexChanged hit during debugging.

Comment: `path = ofd.FileNames;` this seems fishy to me. `path = ofd.FileNames.ToList()` would guarantee you are working with path and not a discarded collection.

Comment: @FelixCastor How converting an array (FileNames) to a List would be useful? Not exactly sure what problem you trying to solve with your comment.

Comment: @Alexi Levenkov, `ofd` is the dialog window and by setting `path = ofd.FileNames` you are assigning a reference to a collection owned by `ofd`.  If afterwards `ofd` disposes of the `FileNames` array then it also disposes of `path`.  Calling the `ToList()` creates a new collection.  Notice the other method references 'path' which leads me to believe it is a property that sticks around after the dialog has been closed.